# Views UI broken after site migration

Tags: views

Ive migrated my site and now my View UI is broken. My relationship 'Relationship: Entity Reference: Referencing entity' works the opposite way round to the way it should. This has been confirmed by a colleague who uses Drupal.

Also fields that ive added to my content type are not available as fields in views, and sometimes the body field is missing too.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I would start to go about fixing this? My Drupal status report doesn't return any errors.

Comment: Looks like you simply encountered a bug in module. Never happened to me, I don't believe anyone will be able to help you, unless you provide more info about migration process - and then it will be helpful only for you, so it's place is in views' issue queue or paid support request, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to agree with @Mołot. There's nothing in the post to indicate what's gone wrong, nor does the error you're seeing make any sense to me. Either we'd need to dissect the migration process, or do site specific in-depth debugging, which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling a custom module has fixed this.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know where the problem originated, but it would be nice if you could be a little more specific about the cause.

Comment: Ive disabled a bunch of modules that I didnt create and the developer who did make them wont be back in the office for a while. Ill post if and when I find out more.